# Adding rows in html vue js based on the select option?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

This is my first row. Based on the select option here, I need to select the different rows

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
    <label class="control-label">Case Type</label>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="Type" id="type">
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Two</option>  
    <option value="Three">Three</option>     
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

If I select option One I need to display the following row

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="form-group label-floating">
 <label class="control-label">Date Released</label>
 <input type="date" class="form-control" v-model="released" required="">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

If I select option Two I need to display the following row

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="form-group label-floating">
 <label class="control-label">Full Name</label>
 <input type="date" class="form-control" v-model="fullname" required="">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

If I select option Three I need to display the following row

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="form-group label-floating">
 <label class="control-label">Address</label>
 <input type="date" class="form-control" v-model="address" required="">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

How can I able to achieve the following case in html vue js? Based on the option selection, I need to display the row as above.

My vue js code is

```
addForm = new Vue({
    el: "#addForm",
    data: {
        Type: '',
        released: '',
        fullname:'',
        address: '',
    },
    methods: {
        handleSubmit: function(e) {
            var vm = this;
            data['Type'] = this.Type;
            data['address'] = this.address;
            data['fullname'] = this.fullname;
            data['released'] = this.released;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/f/',
                data: data,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(e) {
                    if (e.status) {
                        vm.response = e;
                        alert("success")
                    } else {
                        vm.response = e;
                        console.log(vm.response);
                        alert(" Failed") 
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }, 
    },
});
```

I don't want numeric 1,2,3 as values. I need One, Two, Three

Please help me to have a solution

Comment: recreate your problem here https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: Sir nothing to recreate i think.. You might have got my problem

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a v-if on each input / label

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">

     <label class="control-label" v-if="Type == 'One'">Date Released</label>
     <input type="date" class="form-control" v-if="Type == 'One'" v-model="released" required="">

     <label class="control-label" v-if="Type == 'Two'">Full Name</label>
     <input type="date" class="form-control" v-model="fullname" required=""  v-if="Type == 'Two'">

     <label class="control-label" v-if="Type == 'Three'">Address</label>
     <input type="date" class="form-control" v-model="address" required="" v-if="Type == 'Three'">
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Alternatively for the label you could have an object that maps type to text

```
typeMapping: {
  'One': 'Date Released',
  'Two': 'Full Name'
  'Three': 'Address'
}
```

then replace the labels in the first code sample with one label

```
<label class="control-label">typeMapping[Type]</label>
```

Comment: sir, please check my question. Based on the selections I need to display the rows. If I select option as one, i need to add first row, if two, second row and so on

Comment: This will do that. You could put the v-if on the `<div class="row">` if you would like but the code in my answer reduces unnecessary HTML